# No permissions found for security namespace while develop extension for Sure DevOps TFS 2020

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

Im trying to develop a custom extension to my enterprise On-Premise TFS 2020.

When I upload the extension and try to open it I get error in the chrome console: `"No permissions found for security namespace {Git repositories namespace ID} and token {The token of the specific repo}. Ensure that the effective permissions are included in shared data"`

I don't know how to grant permissions to make it work.

Another problem Im facing is the location of the extension. No matter what I put in the "categories" field in the manifest of the extension, It put it in the Azure Repos category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above error is a known issue and has been reported to Microsoft. You can go join the discussion in [this thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/6328).

However, You can just ignore above error. Your extension will still be functioning even if you see this error in the browser console. See my answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776335/console-error-regarding-permissions-for-ms-vss-web-platform).

For the problem of the extension's location, it is not decided by what you put in the`categories`.  The location is controlled by the `Targeting contributions` you specified in the `targets` field of the manifest. See below:

```
"contributions": [
        {
            "id": "my-custom-hub",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-code-web.code-hub-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Code Hub",
                "order": 30,
                "uri": "/views/code/custom.html"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Check the document of [Contribution Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/contributions-overview?view=azure-devops) for more information.

Check the all the [Targetable hub groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/docs/extend/reference/targets/overview#hubs-and-hub-groups) you can place your extension in.

Comment: link hubs-and-hub-groups not working!